# Error: String types not allowed (at 'fail' with value) @values/values.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I am create a login page with twitter account for my app. And the above error is occur when i build my project.

**values/strings.xml**

```
<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: show your `values.xml`

Comment: values/strings.xml? Have you put that style inside Your strings.xml?

Comment: y is style in strings.xml??

Comment: Sorry it is not in values.xml. It is in strings.xml

Comment: its values/styles.xml .. not values.xml .. hope you have corrected it :)

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't**

```
values/strings.xml
```

Wrong path .Put this on your **style** section .

> A style is defined in an XML resource that is separate from the XML
>   that specifies the layout. This XML file resides under res/values/
>   directory of your project and will have  as the root node
>   which is mandatory for the style file.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_styles_and_themes.htm

Comment: Thanks for the Links and Answers to Everyone... I found where i did the mistake and solved it... Thanks again for your help..

Comment: @SanthoshKumarS Glad to hear .Happy to help . Happy coding .

Answer (score 1):

**THIS is values/string.xml**

```
<string name="activity_name">Home</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
```

**THIS is values/style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Custom.Widget.Toolbar</item>
</style>
```

**Both are different things**

Comment: use `style.xml` instead of `Style.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I have get this error and fix it by this way: problem was some style items in **style.xml** file that does not have any value, something like below; just comment or remove that line:
***here is not anything***